# Conditionally format all the cells with dates of the current week

Tags: google-sheets

I have a table that looks like this:

```
some text    14.09.2022
some text    15.09.2022
some text    23.10.2022
```

And I need to conditionally format each cell in the second column if the date in that cell is during the current week.

I have tried different solutions from the Internet[^1], but neither works for me: each time Google Sheets says my formulas are wrong. Any help?

[^1]: For example, I have tried to adopt the formula found [*here*](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/29723262/conditional-formatting-when-date-in-cell-range-is-during-current-week?hl=en).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below custom formula in CF rule.

```
=WEEKNUM($C2)=WEEKNUM(TODAY())
```

[image]